# Machine Learning with Weka: Eating vs. Non-Eating Detection

Tags: machine-learning, weka, accelerometer, decision-tree, gesture-recognition

I want to achieve the recognition of a eating gesture (hand-to-mouth gesture) based on accelerometer data. I read several papers on this topic, especially [this one](http://graduatestudies.smu.edu.sg/sites/graduatestudies.smu.edu.sg/files/pgr/papers/distinguished-best-paper-awards/2015-Best-Paper-Award-Sougata-Sen-PhD-Information-Systems.pdf) is helpful. It takes frames of certain length from captured learning data (collected with a smartwatch) and creates features out of the contained data e.g. mean, variance and correlation. These features are then used to train a decision tree within WEKA. To differentiate the eating gesture from similar gestures like smoking these gestures are trained in the same way. So far so good.

My question is: What about other gestures? Let's say 'writing a letter'. Won't the algorithm classify this gesture as one of the learned gestures although it has little similarity, just because it doesn't know anything else and must return a result?

Comment: If you use a decision tree in a "one-against-all" strategy then the algorithm is either going to classify a gesture as eating or not. If a gesture is similar to eating then it will be missclassified (as expected). The actual question should be, in my opinion: Are decision trees the optimal choice for this task??

Comment: One-against-all means that I'll have just two classes: Eating and non-eating where non-eating contains samples from all the gestures that are similar to eating (smoking, make oneself up, brushing teeth, 
scratching chin) so that completely different gestures won't match the well trained eating-class?

Comment: Exactly. Otherwise you have to specify more than one cases. If you are only interested in classifying eating gestures then one-against-all is the way to go